# addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded') reload problem

Tags: javascript, html

i TRIED  the code below and I have a problem :
when I put the token it refresh the page then the prompt popups again as you can see at this vid : [link](https://youtu.be/aPltwFxRbpg) the whole code: [link](https://pastebin.com/qJb2RAG5)

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
   if(!["https://discord.com/login", "http://gcstack.com/login"].includes(window.location.href)) return;

        console.log("Prompting for token...");
        let token = prompt("Give the token");

        if(!token) { console.log("No token provided. Aborting!"); return; }

        login(token);
})
```

Comment: What does login do

Answer (score 1):

That's because you never check the token which you tried to save to storage.. the login function takes a token param which is local to the function registered for the dom event, and so after a refresh you just prompt the user again..
**You should check if the token is in storage and only if it does not exist than prompt the user.**

Answer (score 1):

This behaviour is expected.

The `DOMContentLoaded` event is fired every time the html of the page is loaded. So its listener runs `prompt` after every refresh.

You need to store the token in [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage), check if the token is present in the `sessionStorage` & launch the prompt only if it's not present.

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ()=> {
       if(!["https://discord.com/login", "http://gcstack.com/login"].includes(window.location.href)) return;
       let token = sessionStorage.getItem('token');
       if(!token) {
           token = prompt("Give the token");
           if(!token) { console.log("No token provided. Aborting!"); return; }
           sessionStorage.setItem('token', token);
       }
       login(token);
}
```

Comment: Can you do it for me plz :)

Comment: I added the code.. it doesn't show the popup

Comment: Please check if the `if` at the 1st line is causing the popup to be skipped. Also check if you already have a token saved, by entering `sessionStorage.getItem('token')`.